# What are the tradeoffs of circularly unfurling solar panel over linearly deploying solar panels?

Tags: mars, solar-power, power, energy, lander

Martian landers like Phoenix and Insight uses circularly unfurling solar panels. The regular satellites make use of linearly unfurling panels.

What are the primary reasons why linear unfurling panels are not used in Martian lander cases? What are the tradeoffs?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind:  Gravity. The circular ones are compact arrangements around a central pole while the linear ones "hang off" to one side and need much heavier supports on a planet.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqKhM.jpg from here: https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-46332684